# Support both light and dark theme in Android Pie

Tags: android, themes, android-9.0-pie

Android Pie added the ability to toggle light/dark theme in the Settings -> Display -> Device Theme menu.

I want my app to apply the correct theme according to the Device Theme set in the device settings.

According to the [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) Android guide, for dark mode the app should use a theme that extends `Theme.AppCompat`, and for light mode the app should use a theme that extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

So I created two themes in my app:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  ...
</style>
```

However in `AndroidManifest.xml` when I declare the application with the `<application>` tag I can only specify one theme in the `android:theme` attribute:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light"
    tools:replace="android:name">
```

How do I declare my application in `AndroidManifest.xml` to **dynamically** pick `@style/AppTheme.Light` or `@style/AppTheme.Dark` according to the Device Theme set in the device settings?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change theme of an already existing activity, call recreate() after setTheme().

Note: don't call recreate if you change theme in onCreate(), to avoid infinite loop.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Call setTheme before creation of any(!) View.
         setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);

        // ...
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to do.

I want the app to apply the correct theme (light/dark) according to the built-in Device Theme settings. In Android Pie this is reachable through Settings -> Display -> Device Theme

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` instead of defining two themes. Its implementation in this video [Cost of a Pixel Color](https://youtu.be/N_6sPd0Jd3g?t=400).

However, when I test this on an emulator, toggling Settings -> Display -> Device Theme menu doesn't work. I have to toggle Developer Options -> Night Mode -> Always On and dark theme is picked automatically.

Since I don't own an Android Pie device, I'm not sure if this is a bug of emulator.